# Bootstrap 3: Collapse show one hide others

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my markup:

```
        <div class="hidden-md" id="mobile-info">

            <p class="text-center">
                <a href="#shopperExperience" class="btn btn-primary switch-chart" data-show-tip="pre-store-preparation" data-chart-title="Consumer Takes Us Through a Shopping Experience" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="shopperExperience" data-parent="#mobile-info">Shopper Experience</a>

                <a href="#productLifeCycle" class="btn btn-primary switch-chart" data-show-tip="growth-over-time" data-chart-title="Understanding the Lifecycle of a Product or Service" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="productLifeCycle" data-parent="#mobile-info">Product/Service Lifecycle</a>
            </p>

            <div id="shopperExperience" class="collapse">
                <%= render 'shared/shopper_exp_mobile_tips' %>
            </div>

            <div id="productLifeCycle" class="collapse">
                <%= render 'shared/product_lifecycle_mobile_tips' %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So, basically when one of the buttons is clicked on, the other areas need to be toggled, but I can't figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 11):

The so called "Accordion" feature (which is what you want to achieve) won't work on BS3 unless you use the right markup.

However I made it work using this little script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('.collapse.in').each(function(){
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="hidden-md" id="mobile-info">
```

```
<p class="text-center">
  <a href="#shopperExperience" class="btn btn-primary switch-chart" data-show-tip="pre-store-preparation" data-chart-title="Consumer Takes Us Through a Shopping Experience" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Shopper Experience</a>

  <a href="#productLifeCycle" class="btn btn-primary switch-chart" data-show-tip="growth-over-time" data-chart-title="Understanding the Lifecycle of a Product or Service" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Product/Service Lifecycle</a>
</p>

<div id="shopperExperience" class="collapse" data-parent="#mobile-info">
  <%=r ender 'shared/shopper_exp_mobile_tips' %>
</div>

<div id="productLifeCycle" class="collapse" data-parent="#mobile-info">
  <%=r ender 'shared/product_lifecycle_mobile_tips' %>
</div>
```

This should Do it for you.

There is a Bug it seems. the `data-parent` depends on `.pannel`

More On the Bug [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966)

Answer (score 2):

If you need this for bootstrap4:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('.collapse.show').each(function(){
                $(this).collapse('hide');
            });
        });
    });
```